# CSS hover problems in Chrome and IE8

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, hover

I'm having trouble with cross-browser compatibility.

I have a simple menu (with all JS functionality removed for the purpose of this demonstration). The background of the links are meant to go orange when hovered over.

- Firefox (V3.6.17): Works properly.
- Chrome (V11.0.696.60): The Main Links expand with `:hover`, shifting all the other menu items. I think the padding or margins expand on hover
- InternetExplorer (V8): The links show in blue despite defining a colour.

I think the problem would easily be recognised by someone who knows CSS well, but my knowledge isn't up to scratch. An explanation would be greatly appreciated!

[Here is the code on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/Ay5FC/5/)

Here is a portion of the CSS:

```
#mainlinks  {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#mainlinks li {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:4px;
    margin:45px 3px 2px 3px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style: none;
}

#mainlinks li :visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    padding:4px;
    margin:45px 3px 2px 3px;
}

#mainlinks li :hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:4px;
    margin:45px 3px 2px 3px;
    background-color:#f1592a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `li:hover` instead of `li :hover`, `li:visited` instead of `li :visited`

hope this works ^^

Comment: Thanks Hatake (and Hristo!) The links don't expand like before, but the link text still shows blue. I'll try Jonathan's suggestion below for that. I will dish out the "Accepted Answer" soon. [Here is the update](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/Y3pnt/) on JSFiddle

Comment: Damn I wish I knew more about CSS. How tags are combined really baffles me. `a` `ul` `li` `:` `hover` etc, I never know which order to put them in and where spaces make a difference or not. **Sigh** I didn't realise I could display an `a` as a block with specific dimensions. I'll try that now.

Answer (score 1):

you should try applying the text specific styles (ie: color) to the 'a' tag instead of on the LI